# Trying to get an average using the contents of two files

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

So I have two files in my directory that contain a number in each of them. I want to make a script that calculates the average of these two numbers. How would I write it? Would this be correct?

```
avg=$((${<file1.txt}-${<file2.txt})/2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example does not work. Furthermore, your formula is probably incorrect. Here are two options without unnecessary `cat`:

```
avg=$(( (`<file1.txt` + `<file2.txt`) / 2 ))
```

or

```
avg=$(( ($(<file1.txt) + $(<file2.txt)) / 2 ))
```

I find the first one more readable though. Also be warned: this trivial approach will cause problems when your files contain more than just the plain numbers.

EDIT:

I should have noted that the first syntactical/legacy option which uses the backticks (` `) is no longer recommended and should be avoided. You can read more about the [WHY](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) here. Thanks at *mklement0* for the link!

EDIT2:

According to Eric, the values are floating point numbers. You can't do this directly in bash because only integer numbers are supported. You have to use a little helper:

```
avg=$(bc <<< "( $(<file1.txt) + $(<file2.txt) ) / 2")
```

or maybe easier to understand

```
avg=$(echo "( $(<file1.txt) + $(<file2.txt) ) / 2" | bc)
```

For those who might wonder what `bc` is (see `man bc`):

> bc  is  a  language that supports arbitrary precision numbers with
>   interactive execution of statements.

---

Here is another alternative since `perl` is usually installed by default:

```
avg=$(perl -e 'print( ($ARGV[0] + $ARGV[1]) / 2 )' -- $(<file1.txt) $(<file2.txt))
```

Comment: So to be more specific, both numbers in the two files are negative numbers. I plugged in the second code that you gave me and it's giving me a syntax error that says: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".6892 + -86.4149) / 2 "). Both numbers by the way are -79.6892 and -86.4149. Any idea what's going wrong here?

Comment: @Eric: The syntactical construct `<<<` is called a  *here string*. See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings and https://linux.die.net/abs-guide/x15683.html for reference. You can think of it as feeding the string on the right into `bc` on the left.

Comment: So overall, would this be okay then for the code? avg=bc <<< "( $(<file1.txt) + $(<file2.txt) ) / 2"

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Of course you have to wrap the whole command in a `$()` so the final output is captured in your variable `avg`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution):

```
avg=$(($(cat file1.txt)-$(cat file2.txt)/2))
```

However, Bash is a pretty bad language for doing maths (at least unless it's completely integer maths). You might want to look into `bc` or a "real" language like Python.